# doubleForColumn not working, int does (Swift)

Tags: sqlite, swift, append

I am pulling some data from a table. `NAME` is a string, `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE` are doubles.

The string is retrieved correctly. However if I try and get `LONGITUDE` as a `doubleForColumn` (which is what it is) I get a compiler error:

> Cannot invoke 'Append' with an argument list of type (Double).

If I use int (which is isn't) the compiler lets it through but returns 0.

Any ideas?

```
locationNames.append(resultSet.stringForColumn("NAME"))
locationLongitude.append(resultSet.doubleForColumn("LONGITUDE"))
locationLatitude.append(resultSet.intForColumn("LATITUDE"))
```

Comment: How are locationLongitude and locationLatitude defined?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `locationLongitude` ?

Comment: Most probably `locationLongitude` & `locationLatitude` are declared as `[Int]` instead of `[Double]`... So passing an int is valid, but converts the double (for example 0.1 -> 0)

Comment: Absolutely right - I was checking the SQL CREATE statement. Apologies for such a crass post.